# Apply same functionality to all programmaticaly created divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have created some divs programmatically with jQuery and I would like to apply the same functionality to all divs.

I have created an example to jsfiddle. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/wm3y5/12/)

As you can see in the example the first `<div class="autosize">` behaves really well but the second `<div class="autosize_2">` does not have any functionality except from the `click` (actually I am not sure why click works).

Can someone help me or give me an example on how to achieve the desired functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work fine if you just add `#pointer_div_2` after every `#pointer_div` separated by a comma.

`$('#pointer_div, #pointer_div_2').on` ... etc.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wm3y5/13/

Basically, you are just targeting *multiple selectors* using the comma

Read more: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: It's working but how can I do this if I am not sure how many divs will be created?

Comment: If you don't know how many `div`s, you could always wrap the entire thing in an `.each()` and target the `div`s using an attribute selector, something like `$('div[id*="pointer_"]').each( ...`

Comment: I changed everything to `class` instead of `div`. check `http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/wm3y5/16/`. Everything is working fine except when I drag inside the 1st div the co-ordinates are marked with - (minus) sign (negative values)..

Comment: Btw multiple selector `Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wm3y5/13/` is not working on Firefox

Answer (score 1):

You could use class="autosize" on all of them. If you actually need unique id's for each you should use id="autosize", id="autosize_2",etc in addition to the class.

Or you could use multiple classes on each:  class="autosize autosize_1", class="autosize autosize_2", etc.

Comment: It is working if I convert it to everything to class but check `http://jsfiddle.net/ntenisOT/wm3y5/16/`. When I click or drag in the firs div the co-ordinates are marked with - (minus) values...

Comment: Yes. Its working. Check the fiddle. I use Chrome btw.. You are right. It is not working in Firefox. And the coordinates are correct for the first image.

Comment: Getting negatives in Chrome but but not in Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 $(document).on('click',selector,handler)
```

in order to attach an handler to all elements matching selector now and in the future.